# Applied id to many similar css

Tags: css

I have form css:

```
p.cl-1{}
p.cl-2{}
```

I use some common attributes, I'll write

```
p[class*=cl-*]{}
```

With ID, What I have written as?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Didn't understand either but the answer may be something like: "`#the_id` and `[id="the_id"]` (`=`, `*=`, `^=` or `$=` are also valid comparisons of course) are valid selectors in CSS if you want to select an element with this id: (HTML) `<element class="whatever1 whatever2" id="the_id">`". EDIT: huge difference is their specificity: 1,0,0 for `#` and only 0,1,0 for attribute selectors